# Is "dogged with questions" a valid use of the work "dogged"?

Tags: word-usage

I just used the phrase *"dogged with questions"* in a sentence, where dogged was meant to mean *"pestered"*, *"bugged"*, *"swamped"* or *"bombarded"*.

Is this valid? I did look up the definition but most examples look like this:

> [Her dogged efforts eventually paid off.](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/dogged)

Suggesting it's closer to *"persistent"*. Also, as I read the definition in my head, I realised it's pronounced *"dog-ed"* not *"docked"*

Google does offer this example:

> [the twenty-nine-year-old has constantly been dogged by controversy](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=define%20dogged&gws_rd=ssl)

But I don't know if the word *"by"* can be replaced with *"with"*, and it is a synonym of *"pestered"*. I'm also not sure whether it's pronounced *"dog-ed"* or *"docked"* in this instance.

Can it be used in the phrase *"dogged with questions"*?

Comment: There are two slightly different words there, pronounced differently.  "Dogged effort" is pronounced as "dog-ed", while "dogged by controversy" is pronounced "dogd", more or less -- just the past-tense of "dog".  The first case is an adjective meaning "persistent", while the second case is a verb meaning "pestered" or "pursued" (as a dog might do in a hunt).

Comment: Ahh so my usage was valid. That’s great

Comment: I'd say "hounded with questions".

Comment: @ab2 - That’s just a more specific type of dog;-)